# spherical coordinates

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

spherical coordinates of point are $(10,20,30)$, the distance between the point and the origin of coordinate system is ?

1- $10$

2- $14.4$

3- $20$

4- $30$

I know that the distance between two points is
$$R=\sqrt{\left(x_2-x_1\right)^2 +\left(y_2-y_1\right)^2+\left(z_2-z_1\right)^2}$$

but when I applied this given $37.41$ which is not in the choice list

Comment: How did you apply a formula that works with points in rectangular coordinates to a spherical coordinate point?

Answer (score 3):

In a [spherical coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), the first coordinate is the radius and the other two are angles.  So the distance of a point from the origin is just the first coordinate.

Comment: Satisfying, succinct, simple. Who could ask for more? + (Oh no, now my compulsive alliterating is kicking in: straight-forward, spot-on, ...